# What is the protocol that web3 uses for interfacing with the blockchain?

Tags: web3js

I need to know how the blockchain loopkup works like blockchain-info. 
I need to also know how web3 api works, how does it interfaces with the blockchain?
What is the protocol that web3 uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web3 uses the [JSON-RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) to talk to the Ethereum node (geth, parity, ethereumj, etc).

Comment: can we say "JSON-RPC" is a protocole ? like HTTP ?

Comment: From https://www.jsonrpc.org/ it is: _A light weight remote procedure call protocol_.